# Conditional Expectation Tower Property proof exercise

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, expected-value

[image]

[image]

In the answer, i'm not sure how do derive the density of Y given Z. Also, why are we integrating with respect to y but not to z? I know by definition that if we're searching for expectation of Y given Z then the integral would be with respect to Y. But here we have a function of both Z and Y

Comment: Since we are computing the conditional expectation, we are considering only events conditioned on $Z = z$, i.e., the value of $Z$ is fixed to be $z$. Thus, when we are evaluating the expectation of $h(Y, Z)$ conditioned on $Z = z$, we are essentially evaluating the expectation of $h(Y,z)$ where the only source of randomness is $Y$ and hence the integration is over only $y$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 ohhh, okay, i see now, thanks!

Comment: what about my first question?

Comment: The definition of the conditional density of $Y|Z$ is similar to the others given in the first part. It is given as $\displaystyle f_{Y|Z}(y|z ) = \frac{f_{Y,Z}(y,z)}{f_Z(z)}$ whenever the denominator is non-zero.